# Finding the pivot point in a rotated array which has been shifted from kth element

Tags: c, array, sorting, binary-search

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Joker has a deck of n cards, each with a value written on it. The cards are arranged in ascending order from top to bottom. Joker's master performs a hidden operation: picking a random number k between 0 and n, and moving the top k cards to the bottom. This results in a new arrangement: (ak+1, ak+2, ..., an, a1, a2, ..., ak). Joker's task is to figure out the value of k using as few queries as possible.

> a) Design an algorithm with O(log(n)) complexity to help Joker find the value of k.
> b) Provide a time complexity analysis for your strategy.

In simpler terms, Joker wants to know how many cards were moved from the top to the bottom of the deck by his master. You need to come up with a method to determine this efficiently, using only a logarithmic number of queries, and analyze the time complexity of the approach.

Here I'm thinking we find the pivot k by using the following method:

```
int findPivot(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    // Base cases
    if (high < low)
        return -1;
    if (high == low)
        return low;
 
    // low + (high - low)/2;
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (mid < high && arr[mid] > arr[mid + 1])
        return mid;
 
    if (mid > low && arr[mid] < arr[mid - 1])
        return (mid - 1);
 
    if (arr[low] >= arr[mid])
        return findPivot(arr, low, mid - 1);
 
    return findPivot(arr, mid + 1, high);
}
```

Where the function call shall be:

```
int pivot = findPivot(arr, 0, n - 1);
```

This shall take at most O(log n) time complexity. I was hoping to find a better solution for this classic problem. It'll be helpful if you can help me optimise the solution.

Comment: Can you show your tests for this?  That would help reviewers.

Comment: I just dry ran the code and thought if there could be any better solutions

Comment: Write down the [invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant), please. Be specific, to avoid [OBOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)s.

Comment: @J_H the code shall call `findPivot` on either the left or right subarray based on comparisons with `arr[low]` and `arr[mid]`. The range is adjusted to either the left or right half, ensuring that the algorithm explores the correct subarray.

Comment: @driver, yeah, that much is clear, a simple reference to the well-known [Binary Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Alternative_procedure) suffices. But Knuth notes that implementation details can be surprisingly tricky. I was asking you to write down those details, distinguishing between `<` and `<=`. Minimally, write down the pre- and post- conditions that are always true. Suppose one or more duplicate card values appear at the split `k`. This source code doesn't make it readily apparent if it will report a higher or lower result index.

Comment: Shouldn't that be clear from the problem statement about what needs to be done?